# How to change the locale when useing i18n in Android?

Tags: android, internationalization

I want to develop an app supporting some language. I don't know how to set the locale. So user can change any language he want. Now I only know that android will try to set the XX/strings.xml automatically according to the device setting. How to set it by manual?

Answer (score 0):

GO into your settings.  THere should be a language and keyboards setting.  Change it to whatever language you want.

Comment: I want to change my own app's setting not the device setting

Comment: The system is set so there's a single device setting.  I don't think it's possible to change just your app.